# Pandas cumulative function of series with dates and NaT

Tags: python, pandas

This may be a known limitation, but I'm struggling to calculate the cumulative minimum of a series in Pandas when that series contains NaT's.  Is there a way to make this work?

Simple example below:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(pd.date_range('2008-09-15', periods=10, freq='m'))
s.loc[10] = pd.NaT
s.cummin()

ValueError: Could not convert object to NumPy datetime
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [bug has been fixed](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/8966) in Pandas 0.15.2 (to be released).

---

As a workaround, you could use `skipna=False`, and handle the NaTs "manually":

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)

s = pd.Series(pd.date_range('2008-09-15', periods=10, freq='m'))
s.loc[10] = pd.NaT
np.random.shuffle(s)
print(s)
# 0    2008-11-30
# 1    2008-12-31
# 2    2009-01-31
# 3    2009-06-30
# 4    2008-10-31
# 5    2009-03-31
# 6    2008-09-30
# 7    2009-04-30
# 8           NaT
# 9    2009-05-31
# 10   2009-02-28
# dtype: datetime64[ns]

mask = pd.isnull(s)
result = s.cummin(skipna=False)
result.loc[mask] = pd.NaT
print(result)
```

yields

```
0    2008-11-30
1    2008-11-30
2    2008-11-30
3    2008-11-30
4    2008-10-31
5    2008-10-31
6    2008-09-30
7    2008-09-30
8           NaT
9    2008-09-30
10   2008-09-30
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Actually all I needed was `skipna=False`...thought I'd checked that but I guess not.  Thanks!

Comment: @unutbu can u make a bug issue of this on github - this should work